# How to display an object's attribute as a different string?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3: I have a table with one column showing true or false based on the objects boolean attribute. I want it to show yes or no.

Here is my table:

```
<table id="resellers" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" style="background-color: white">
<thead>
    <button type="button" class="reset">Reset Search</button>
    <th width="12%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Contact Name</th>
    <th width="12%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Reseller</th>
    <th width="11%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Region</th>
    <th width="10%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Country</th>
    <th width="18%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Email</th>
    <th width="11%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Distributor</th>
    <th width="11%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Registered</th>
    <th width="10%" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#00F'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'">Approved</th>
    <th width="5%" class="filter-false"></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <% #current_grandstreamer.resellers.each do |reseller| %>
    <% @resellers.each do |reseller| %>

            <tr>
                <td><%= reseller.contact_name %></td>
                <td><%= link_to reseller.company_name, grandstreamers_reseller_path(reseller) %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.company_region %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.company_country %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.contact_email %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.distributor %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.created_at.to_date.to_s %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.approved %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_grandstreamers_reseller_path(reseller) %>
            </tr>

    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Is there a way to do an if statement or make a variable in the controller to display?
Thanks

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, a [`<thead>` can only have `<tr>` children](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/thead.html#thead-content-model).

Comment: Invalid for HTML, read the spec I linked to. Don't be surprised if browsers rewrite your not-quite-HTML in various ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
<%= reseller.approved ? "Yes" : "No" %>
```

Comment: Wow, that is awesome! :) Thanks. Do you have a source of where I could read about this technique?

Comment: It's called a ternary operator. Just about all languages have one. Here's a page with a few Ruby examples and explanation: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/examples-ruby-ternary-operator-true-false-syntax

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is extend the boolean classes with a to_yesno helper.

```
config/initializers/ruby_extensions.rb:

class TrueClass
  def to_yesno
    'yes'
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def to_yesno
    'no'
  end
end
```

Then in my views, for any boolean value I can just do:

```
<%= reseller.approved.to_yesno %>
```